# Youtube API check someone's channel subscription

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I'm developing an app where a user can subscribe to someone else channel. I know it's not a good idea but I'm just doing an experiment.

Here's an example of an app where users can subscribe to someone else channel and the good thing is that you won't get any point if you didn't subscribe to that channel.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pnsulabs.subsbooster

What I want to do:

- There's a person A and Person B.
- I want to detect if person A has subscribed to the Person B channel.

I think it's possible but I don't know how to do that.

I'm doing this in Flutter. Could anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: The YouTube Data API *does not allow* a third-party to retrieve the subscriptions of a given person (that has an YouTube account) *unless the respective person grants to the third-party explicit permission*.

Comment: But there are so many apps that are using functionality.. How they're doing this

Comment: can u mention few examples which use that functionality?

Comment: I Already Added an app using the same functionality as I want it.